# Image size - Python

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, resolution, dpi, image-size

I have the following figure drawn in Python. If you look carefully, the length from 0 to 4000 in the x-axis is not the same as that of in y-axis. How can I fix this one in the code? I tried putting `plt.figure(figsize=(10,10), dpi = 100)`, but didn't work.

This is the code that I use to save this figure.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) 
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(T, pos=pos, node_size=15, node_color=color_map, node_shape='o', alpha=1.0)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(T,pos=pos,width=1.0, edge_color='b', style='solid', alpha=None)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(T,pos=pos, font_size=4, font_color='k', font_family='sans-serif', font_weight='normal', alpha=1.0)
plt.axis('on')
plt.title('Graph')
plt.savefig ( "Graph.pdf")
```

[image]

Comment: It is not clear from your question what are you trying to achieve. Are you trying to make sure the 0-4000 on the x-axis will have the same length as 0-4000 on the y-axis? Or, maybe you are just trying to make both axes have same pixel-wise length, regardless of their scale?

Comment: I suggest you add a minimal example. I tried the following and the length of the axes seems to be the same: ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.figure(figsize=(5,5)); plt.plot([250,4000],[500,5000]); plt.show()```

Comment: You just need to set the axis limits explicitly: `plt.axis(0, 5000, 0, 5000)`